# PHPEXCEL cambiar formato de fecha

Tags: php, date, phpexcel, formato

Estoy teniendo un problema al recoger fechas de la base de datos con `PHP` y mostrarlas en un `xls`. Os comento, tengo una base de datos donde los campos con fechas se muestran con este formato: **2017-04-07 00:00:00**

Leo estos datos con una consulta y los escribo en un `xls` usando la librería `PHPEXCEL`, mi problema es que necesito obtener las fechas en formato **dd/mm/aaaa** y sólo estoy consiguiendo obtener el mismo formato de la base de datos con `$sheet->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(10,$fila,$row['FUV']);` o si utilizo el siguiente código para la fecha que he puesto antes:

```
$sheet->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(10,$fila,PHPExcel_Shared_Date::PHPToExcel($row['FUV']));
```

Obtengo el número **42415** en la celda.

Sé que estoy haciendo algo mal o me falta algo por hacer pero no veo mas información.

Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eso puedes hacerlo en la consulta `SELECT` que trae los datos de la base de datos, aplicando **[`DATE_FORMAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)** a la columna de fecha.

Por ejemplo, asumiendo que tu columna se llama `FUV`, sería cuestión de escribir la consulta así:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(FUV, "%d-%m-%Y") AS FUV FROM tuTabla;
```

Haciendo eso, la columna `FUV` ya vendrá en formato `dd-mm-yyyy` y podrás mostrarla tal cual en el Excel.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, no había caído en hacerlo en la consulta, he tenido que usar el equivalente para sql server pero me ha solucionado el problema

Answer (score 1):

Pongo el equivalente de la solución para sql_server por si a alguien le ayuda:

```
SELECT FORMAT(FUV,'dd/MM/yyyy') AS FUV FROM tabla
```

Answer (score 0):

Al crear el `xls` con `PHPEXCEL`, pásale el dato formateado

```
$sheet->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('B10', date("d/m/Y",strtotime($row['FUV'])));
```

... no se si así te puede valer